# Chrome browser - printing tables with multiple rows in headers issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, printing

**The goal** - to print pages with tables the following way:

1. If the whole table is taller than A4 paper list, to duplicate headers for each page
2. If the table is smaller than A4 paper list, to not break the page before next table

For one-row headers, this CSS property works as it should:

```
page-break-inside:auto;
```

**The problem** - it comes by using more complicated table headers with 2+ rows, when such headers are somewhere at the middle of page break.

For better reference, here is the sample table code which can be used. Please be sure to open HTML file with this code only, without any additional code usually provided by build-in code snippet tool:

```html
<style>
    td {
        border: 1px solid lightblue;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    table {
        page-break-inside: auto;
    }

    tbody td {
        border: 1px solid blue;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
</style>
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table header 1</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table header 2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table header 3</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 1</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 3</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 4</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 5</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 6</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 7</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 8</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 9</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 10</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 11</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 12</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 13</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 14</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 15</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 16</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 17</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 18</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 19</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <thead>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table header 1</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table header 2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table header 3</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 1</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>this is table body 2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

If you try to print the following HTML page, this issue appears:
[screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dhZ5O.jpg)

**What was tried**

different combinations of all page-break related properties for table header tags.

Comment: Your experience is not uncommon and stems from the use of a non-print medium to try and create sophisticated print from it. I do not believe you will ever get browser's to understand the concept of print.

Comment: You should use page-break outside of table element, you cannot use it with thead. If you put page-break to relative parent container of table, browsers will automatically add header to the next page.

Comment: @AliDemirci any chance to provide working example based on very simple code above? Nothing like this works on my end

Comment: @MaxT Added as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```css
  td {
    border: 1px solid lightblue;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  tbody td {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .avoid-page-break {
    page-break-inside: avoid;
    break-inside: avoid;
    position: relative;
  }
```

```html
<div class="avoid-page-break">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>HEAD OF TABLE 1</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>HEAD OF TABLE 1</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>HEAD OF TABLE 1</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 1</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 2</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 3</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 4</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 5</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 6</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 7</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 8</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 9</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 10</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 11</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 12</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 13</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 14</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 15</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 16</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 17</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 18</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 19</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 19</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 19</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 19</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 19</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 19</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 19</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 19</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 19</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 19</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 19</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 19</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 19</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="avoid-page-break">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>HEAD OF TABLE 2</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>HEAD OF TABLE 2</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>HEAD OF TABLE 2</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 1</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div>this is table body 2</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. If I extend your solution by adding more tables, eg https://jsfiddle.net/jpf9as26/1/, we can see that there are some huge gaps between tables at some places. Example - https://ibb.co/ZfpfQCx. This is not corresponding with #2 of the goal. 

If I change to page-break-inside: auto; - then the same issue appears which was described

Comment: @MaxT how about removing `break-inside` and changing `page-break-inside` to `page-break-after`?